# Is there way to batch insert and ignore any FK constraints errors?

Tags: java, foreign-keys, jooq

There are `Parent` table (with PK constraint) and `Child` table (maybe without PK, but with FK constraint for `Parent` table).

I want to batch insert in `Child` table and ignore/skip all rows with FK constraints errors (such as `onConflictOnConstraint()` for `insertInto` for single row) and save other rows.

I tried `dslContext.loadInto()` with `onErrorIgnore()` option, but if any errors occur, other rows will not be inserted either:

```
List<Record2<Object, Object>> records = List.of(
        dslContext.newRecord(field("id"), field("value")).values(1, "1"),
        dslContext.newRecord(field("id"), field("value")).values(2, "2"),
        dslContext.newRecord(field("id"), field("value")).values(3, "3"),
        dslContext.newRecord(field("id"), field("value")).values(3, "3"));
dslContext.loadInto(table("child"))
        .batchAll()
        .onErrorIgnore()
        .loadRecords(records)
        .fields(field("id"), field("value"))
        .execute();
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @LukasEder I'm using Postgres and MySQL

Comment: @LukasEder I also never managed to get `.onErrorIgnore()` to work, and my best theory is that when used with Spring the underlying exception is wrapped into `DataIntegrityViolation` and jOOQ doesn't catch it as `DataAccessException`, so doesn't handle it. But this is mostly a wild guess.